# as.Date behavoir for large numeric arguments

Tags: r

I am trying to understand the way R dates works.

In open source R, one day after 31/12/9999, the character version of the date rolls over to 01/01/0000.

```
max.date <- as.numeric(as.Date("9999-12-31", origin = '1970-01-01', format = '%Y-%m-%d'))
max.date
as.Date(max.date + 1, origin = '1970-01-01')
as.numeric(as.Date(max.date + 1, origin = '1970-01-01'))
```

If you try to enter a date one day after 31/12/9999 as a string, you get a missing value.

```
as.Date("10000-01-01", origin = '1970-01-01', format = '%Y-%m-%d')
```

As you increment a numeric argument to `as.Date` after 31/12/9999, the years just roll over like an odometer until you reach 2^32 - 1.

My question is why do the year roll over and is there a way to control this?

Comment: Out of interest, what's your use case?

Comment: I have no real use for dates past 9999 AD.  I am writing a bunch of performance tests for R and wanted to test the speed of `as.Date`.  When I wrote the test, I included values that gave weird results and it piqued my interest.

Comment: When will people take the [Y10K problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_10,000_problem) seriously? The clock is ticking!

Answer (score 1):

Dates and times are horrendously complicated things (once you consider leap years and days, different formatting styles, and time zones).  As you've spotted, the R date-time classes only deal with the range `0001-01-01` to `9999-12-31`.

Even then, the dates are Gregorian, so you need to be careful with dates before 1752, or from countries where other calendars are used.

The `ConvCalendar` package lets you convert to some other calendar systems (some current ones like Islamic and Chinese; some obsolete ones like Julian and French Revolutionary).  AFAIK, none of them stretch forward in time enough to handle [Warhammer 40k](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wh40k) dates.

Comment: I agree, but essentially you are counting days (for the case of `as.Date` past the origin.  R is doing that and keeping track of leap year, etc., fine.  It is just displaying and storing the result with a truncated year.  My question is: why does it do that?

Comment: @ChristopherLouden probably because of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Years